# What's the difference between the various GetLogicalDrives methods and which one is better to use

Tags: c#

I tried to get the name or letter of the hard drive, but still confused because here there are several functions that can be used.
what's the difference between the three codes below to get a hard drive letter? and which one is better to use?

```
Directory.GetLogicalDrives()
Environment.GetLogicalDrives()
DriveInfo.GetDrives()
```

result : [image: get hard drive letter]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They all call this code, which is just a wrapper for the *Win32 API* [GetLogicalDrives function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlogicaldrives)

```
new EnvironmentPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted).Demand();

int drives = Win32Native.GetLogicalDrives();
if (drives == 0)
   __Error.WinIOError();
uint d = (uint)drives;
int count = 0;
while (d != 0)
{
   if (((int)d & 1) != 0) count++;
   d >>= 1;
}
String[] result = new String[count];
char[] root = new char[] { 'A', ':', '\\' };
d = (uint)drives;
count = 0;
while (d != 0)
{
   if (((int)d & 1) != 0)
   {
      result[count++] = new String(root);
   }
   d >>= 1;
   root[0]++;
}
return result;
```

With the exception being that the [`GetDrives`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives?view=netframework-4.7.2) passes the results to the [`DriveInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) class

```
// Directory.GetLogicalDrives demands unmanaged code permission
String[] drives = Directory.GetLogicalDrives();
DriveInfo[] di = new DriveInfo[drives.Length];
for(int i=0; i<drives.Length; i++)
     di[i] = new DriveInfo(drives[i]);
return di;
```

So the answer is, there is no appreciable diffrence

---

**References**

- [Reference source Directory.GetLogicalDrives()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs,b2738f5b7e5ae558)
- [Reference source Environment.GetLogicalDrives()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/d4119bc41b33ece9.html)
- [Reference source DriveInfo.GetDrives()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/driveinfo.cs,8daa70509a84df48)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getlogicaldrives?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetLogicalDrives) [would](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getlogicaldrives?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Environment_GetLogicalDrives) [suggest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_DriveInfo_GetDrives) that these three methods provide the same information.  Only DriveInfo.GetDrives() would seem to suggest that more information is given, but if you only need to know the actual letters, then the first two is more than sufficient.